# I want to buy the unlock all key for project diva, do I need all the packs and bundles?

Tags: ps4, project-diva-future-tone

I have project diva future tone.

I don't really want to spend on the packs but they have great models and accessories, so I was wondering if I buy the unlock all key will it give me every model including the ones from other packs?

Or will it only unlock all the models from the bundles I already own?